# Kazam: Screencast, then editing: Lost quality and increased size

Tags: screencast, openshot

I recorded a small screencast with the tool Kazam on Ubuntu 18.04.

I am amazed: 7 seconds have only 73kByte. Format: webm

Now I edited the screencast: I cut some seconds at the end.

I did this with OpenShot.

Now the screencast has only 4 seconds. But if I save it, its size has increased (140kByte) and the quality is much lower.

How to record, edit and save a screencast without loosing the small file size and the quality?

It would be nice to have a GUI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) instead of with a GUI application. Simply:

```
 ffmpeg -i video.webm -ss 00:00:01 -t 00:00:08 -async 1 cut.webm
```

It would save your video size.

If you want [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) with a GUI, you can try [Handbreak](https://handbrake.fr/) which is based on [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/).

Comment: It would be nice to have some GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Even though OpenShot does not have a "Simple" profile for WebM, you can still use it.

For that, you must have version 0.6+ of FFmpeg (which is included in Ubuntu 10.10). For older versions of Ubuntu you will not be able to use WebM, unless you upgrade FFmpeg.

Switch to the "Advanced" tab on the export screen in OpenShot, and use the screenshot as a guide. I have highlighted the most important settings.

[image]

Or else try [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/), it has a really neat GUI to edit videos!